# Need to perform neural network on large dataset in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a massive training dataset of over 200k columns, and 1million rows. My local computer has a RAM of 64GB, and 1TB SSD. Since the column count is massive, it always crashes and unable to train any neural network model on this. What should I do?
Note: I don't have resources to use the cloud, nor buy hardware.

Comment: You are not saying what tools you are using for estimating your network. Most training algorithms allow for training in batches. Try searching for that (batches training )for the package you are using.

Comment: Maybe spark could be an option

Comment: The problem is that for me to train a neural network model, I need all my data in a dataframe. For instance, using the package neuralnet. However, my datasize is too large to even be stored in a normal matrix. It is currently stored in a sparse matrix, and although I can do SVM and GLMNET using the sparse matrix, I cannot train a neural network model on that data.

Comment: this is a bit of a "I feed a million people. I have only a loaf of bread and two fishes. What should I do?" type situation  what options have you explored so far? what opportunities are available to you right now (e.g. if you are a student, I know some websites allow cheap or free access to their tools). Would you be open to training your model on a smaller subset of the data?

Comment: if it's in a sparse matrix, maybe using Spark could be an option then OP, because the sparse matrix is by definition spread out, filled with zeros, so a more tightly organised dataset/a SQL database would take up much less room, and so be much less likely to crash

Comment: In my experience ~200 billion data points is too large for a local computer. How many of your 200k columns could possibly be useful predictors? I have started with a ~50k column dataset before, but I whittled it down to ~1000 columns before building models by e.g. removing columns with near-zero variance, testing for multicollinearity, etc (there are many, many tutorials for feature selection out there). When you talk about using a sparse matrix, are many/most of your values zero? If all of your columns are numeric, maybe start with xgboost to get proof of concept, then move to NNs. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Mark, I am not open to training a smaller subset of data. With regards to hardware, my system has 32 gb ram and 1tb ssd. However, I also have access to 3tb ssd. I tried using spark, but in order to convert data to a Spark Dataframe, I need it to first be a dataframe. However, a dataframe cannot hold the large amount of data

Comment: Hey Jared. Yes, all my columns have mostly zeros cause the data is full of 0s and 1s only. How do I move to NNs when I am not able to?

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on the type of data. Let's assume it's numerical values. Let's see how much memory it occupies.

```
> format(object.size(matrix(1.1, 1e4, 2e5)), units = "GB")
[1] "14.9 Gb"
```

So 10K rows of 200K columns can fit in the memory of your machine. So all you need is to train with a batch size that fits the data in the memory of your machine (e.g., 10K).

Answer (score 0):

That's a massive number of columns.  I think I would probably take statistical sample of 1,000 rows and perform PCA.  The PCA loadings on this sample could be used to reduce the 200k columns down to ~200 on the full data set.

Comment: I understand that 200k columns is simply too much. However, I'm doing research which requires me to use all the 200k columns to display certain details.